# Complex analysis - existence of field $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

In the following: $\mathbb{F}$ is defined to be a field containing $\mathbb{R}$ and in which the equation $x^{2}+1=0$ can be solved.

Then define a set $\mathbb{C}$ to be subset of $\mathbb{F}$ whose elements are of the form $x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ where $+$ and $i$ have only symbollical meaning. Defining addition and multiplication in usual way, then $\mathbb{C}$ is indeed a field: but here is what I do not understand;

How does the fact that we can write

$x+iy=(x+i0)+y(0+i1)$

shows that in fact $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are identical? I presume it somehow shows that $\mathbb{F}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{F}$ but I don't have any clear idea why this is.

Also, when we say field of all polynomials modulo polynomial $x^{2}+1$, what does this exactly mean?

And some basic algebraic manipulation question: is there any nice way of putting $(1-i)^{n}+(1+i)^{n}$ in a closed form, except for expressing them in modulus-argument form then using de'Moivre? I could try using binomial theorem but after a few steps it is redueced to sums of binomial coefficients which I could not put in a closed form.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing some hypotheses (presumably that $F$ is an algebraic extension of $\Bbb R$). There are (big) fields over $\Bbb R$ that are algebraically closed and strictly contain $\Bbb C$.

Comment: They are not identical. $F$ could be transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$. Also, unless $i$ have more specific meaning, the $\mathbb{C}$ you get is not necessarily what people would call a complex field (or a field, for that matter)

Comment: The first part came from the book by Lars v Ahlfors. I guess since this was aimed at people who first encountered complex analysis, he didn't go into much detail. But in case we indeed had $\mathbb{C}$=$\mathbb{F}$, (with any hypothesis required) how does above argument shows that $\mathbb{C}$=$\mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 2):

The smallest field extension of $\Bbb R$ in which the irreducible polynomial $x^2 + 1$ has a root is $\Bbb R[x] / (x^2 + 1)$. We want to find an isomorphism between $\Bbb R[x] / (x^2 + 1)$ and $\Bbb C$. To do this, define a homomorphism $\varphi : \Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb C$, $\varphi(x) = i$. By direct computation, the ideal $(x^2 + 1)$ is in the kernel. Since $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible and $\Bbb R[x]$ is a PID, $(x^2 + 1)$ is maximal. Thus $\ker \varphi = (x^2 + 1)$. Now the first isomorphism gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I guess I dont fully follow your arguments. I didn't have any idea what polynomials modulo $x^{2}+1$ meant at first place.

Comment: @user160738 What's the context of this question? Did you study quotients of polynomial rings? What about field extensions?

Comment: Sorry about that - I should have indicated what background I had. I only have vague idea what rings are (and non for field extensions), and did not study in any depth (just ended my 1st year in undergrad maths). The original question said: 'for students who have background in algebra' but since I was not sure how much algebra this meant, I thought I would try.

Comment: @user160738 No problem at all. I've seen your comment above. I think this is what the author had in mind, but it does require some background in ring theory. Particularly, you need to study quotients of polynomial rings and the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb C$ can be defined as $\mathbb R[X]/(x^2+1)$. This is a quotient of a ring by a maximal ideal*, so that it is a field. Now, by properties of quotients, we have two corollaries:

i ) Every polynomial in the quotient has degree less than that of $x^2+1$, so that every element of the quotient is of the form $a+bx$

ii)The element $x^2+1$ is the kernel of the map , so that $x^2+1=0 \rightarrow x^2=-1$

So we have a field with elements of the form $ax+b$ , with the property that $x^2=-1$. Then the map $ax+b \rightarrow ai+b$ is a field isomorphism.

- Because it is an ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. That point i) gave me a clear idea.

Comment: Glad it helped.